# Prepend uri to url path in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

My service api is exposed on port 9000 at `http://localhost:9000/api`. I'd like to be able to prepend `/service` to this uri. I want the url to look like: `http://localhost:9000/service/api`. However, I only want to make this change at the networking level not the application level. How can I do this in docker-compose?

The reason why I want todo this is that, in prod, my app runs in EKS. Here we prepend this `/service` to the uri. I want to replicate this behaviour when running my app locally from docker-compose. Is it possible?

```
version: '3.0'
services:
  neo4j:
    container_name: ${SERVICE_NAME:-service-api}-neo4j-${BUILD:-local}-${GIT_HASH}
    image: neo4j:${NEO4J_VERSION:-4.4.8-enterprise}
    volumes:
      - ./docker/neo4j/plugins:/plugins
      - ./docker/neo4j/conf:/conf
      - ./docker/neo4j/import:/import
    environment:
      NEO4J_AUTH: neo4j/pass
      NEO4J_dbms_logs_debug_level: DEBUG
      NEO4J_ACCEPT_LICENSE_AGREEMENT: "yes"
    ports:
      - "17687:7687"
      - "17474:7474"
    networks:
      - ${SERVICE_NAME:-service-api}

  service-api:
    container_name: ${SERVICE_NAME:-service-api}-${BUILD:-local}-${GIT_HASH}
    build:
      args:
        SERVICE_NAME: ${SERVICE_NAME:-service-api}
      context: ./docker/${SERVICE_NAME:-service-api}
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - neo4j
    environment:
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: local
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - ${SERVICE_NAME:-service-api}

networks:
  service-api:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: Add a webserver reverse proxy service in front of your application which will map `/service` to your application

Answer (score 2):

Docker can't do this.  `ports:` or the equivalent `docker run -p` option only forwards a TCP connection from a host port to a container port, but it does no inspection or modification of the contents of the network stream.  More concretely this means that Docker knows nothing about URL paths, and you can't change URL layouts using only Docker or Compose settings.

Your setup doesn't appear to include any sort of reverse proxy.  Some applications will include a reverse proxy, usually based on Nginx or Apache HTTPD, often to make front- and back-end services appear on the same port.  If you had a proxy like this then it could do this URL remapping, and it's possible you could provide a path prefix as an environment variable in the Compose file.  Setting this up is a little more involved than fits in this answer, though.

(EKS also doesn't intrinsically do this remapping, but if you're using a Kubernetes Ingress object, that does fill the same role of the reverse proxy.)